# how to minimize a function using Deap?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, deap

I need to minimize a function using genetic algorithm and PSO.

Different posts suggest to use [DEAP](https://code.google.com/p/deap/) (I am using python) but I do not even understand how to start.

We can consider for example f on the interval i

```
i=arange(-10,10,0.1)
def f(x):
    return x*sin(x)
```

How can I minimize this function using DEAP?

Comment: There's no 'DEAP' tag unfortunately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have solved.

This is my code

```
t1=linspace(-50,50,100)
sig1=sin(t1/2)+np.random.normal(scale=0.1,size=len(t1))
sig2=sin(t1/2)+np.random.normal(scale=0.1,size=len(t1))



f0=interp1d(t1,sig1,kind="cubic",bounds_error=False,fill_value=-10000)
g=interp1d(t1,sig2,kind="cubic",bounds_error=False,fill_value=10000)
#true value that  I would like to estimate
A=2
B=0.8
C=0

def s(t):
    return A+B*t+C*t*t

def inv_s(t):
    return (t-B)/A

def f(t):
    return f0(s(t))

def hat_s(t,a,b):
    return t*b+a


Ig=arange(t1.min(),t1.max(),1)
If=(Ig-A)/B
I_min=max(If.min(),Ig.min())
I_max=min(If.max(),Ig.max())


J=linspace(min(If.min(),Ig.min()),max(If.max(),Ig.max()))
I=linspace(I_min,I_max,1000)  

#plot(J,f(J),J,g(J))
#ylim(-1.2,1.2)


def cost(x,T=I):
    a=x[0]
    b=x[1]
    return norm(g(b*T+a)-f(T))/len(T),







import operator
import random

import numpy

from deap import base
from deap import benchmarks
from deap import creator
from deap import tools

creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0,))
creator.create("Particle", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax, speed=list, 
    smin=None, smax=None, best=None)

def generate(size, pmin, pmax, smin, smax):
    part = creator.Particle(random.uniform(pmin, pmax) for _ in range(size)) 
    part.speed = [random.uniform(smin, smax) for _ in range(size)]
    part.smin = smin
    part.smax = smax
    return part

def updateParticle(part, best, phi1, phi2):
    u1 = (random.uniform(0, phi1) for _ in range(len(part)))
    u2 = (random.uniform(0, phi2) for _ in range(len(part)))
    v_u1 = map(operator.mul, u1, map(operator.sub, part.best, part))
    v_u2 = map(operator.mul, u2, map(operator.sub, best, part))
    part.speed = list(map(operator.add, part.speed, map(operator.add, v_u1, v_u2)))
    for i, speed in enumerate(part.speed):
        if speed < part.smin:
            part.speed[i] = part.smin
        elif speed > part.smax:
            part.speed[i] = part.smax
    part[:] = list(map(operator.add, part, part.speed))

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("particle", generate, size=2, pmin=-6, pmax=6, smin=-3, smax=3)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.particle)
toolbox.register("update", updateParticle, phi1=2.0, phi2=2.0)
toolbox.register("evaluate", cost)

def main():
    pop = toolbox.population(n=5)
    stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats.register("avg", numpy.mean)
    stats.register("std", numpy.std)
    stats.register("min", numpy.min)
    stats.register("max", numpy.max)

    logbook = tools.Logbook()
    logbook.header = ["gen", "evals"] + stats.fields

    GEN = 1000
    best = None

    for g in range(GEN):
        for part in pop:
            part.fitness.values = toolbox.evaluate(part)
            if not part.best or part.best.fitness < part.fitness:
                part.best = creator.Particle(part)
                part.best.fitness.values = part.fitness.values
            if not best or best.fitness < part.fitness:
                best = creator.Particle(part)
                best.fitness.values = part.fitness.values
        for part in pop:
            toolbox.update(part, best)

        # Gather all the fitnesses in one list and print the stats
        logbook.record(gen=g, evals=len(pop), **stats.compile(pop))
        print(logbook.stream)
        print "  Best so far: %s - %s" % (best, best.fitness)

    return pop, logbook, best

pop,logbook,best= main()
print "best=",best,"A,B=",(A,B)
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually there is an example for that : http://deap.rtfd.org/en/master/examples/pso_basic.html

Note that I'm a DEAP developer.

Answer (score 2):

I realise I'm late in my reply but hopefully I can help someone out there new to the DEAP library.

In order to minimise you must create a FitnessMin class as shown below:

```
creator.create("FitnessMin", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0,))
```

Note how I have a weight of -1.0, if we were to have this as 1.0 we would be maximising.

Then once you do this, apply the fitness class to your Individual, which is essentially the Chromosome you wish to train:

```
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMin)
```

Take a look at eaSimple in the DEAP library as it is the best one to start with. Here is a list of algorithms provided by DEAP out of the box: http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/algo.html

Answer (score 1):

I've changed `weights=(1.0,)` to `weights=(-1.0,)` in base fitness.

It's work!